# Missing libraries with oracle-java7-jdk in eclipse on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I recently installed the ubuntu 12.04 final beta

After installing the oracle jdk from the webupd8 ppa, launching eclipse failed complaining about a missing shared library.

```
Can't load library: /home/bob/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-3740.so
```

I searched around, and found this quesion: [Eclipse cannot load SWT libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/ubuntu-eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries-not-opening)

As the OP recommended, I tried switching to open-jdk, and that worked wonderfully. The problem, however, is that I am working on a project that doesn't support openjdk.

I tried the second solution as well (the one by scott, which was just creating symbolic links to /usr/lib/jni/... in ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/). Eclipse launches and everything is fine, but it still misses some libraries; this is what I get when i try to run my project:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libgdx/1352105074/libjogl_awt-linux64.so: libjawt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I know libjawt.so is somewhere on my computer:

```
$ locate libjawt.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
```

But eclipse or java seems to think that libraries should be placed in ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64, isn't that weird?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse when launched defaults to its own internal JRE, as I understand. I recommend the following:

1. Modify your CLASSPATH variable to include the path to the desired libraries;
2. Set your JAVA_HOME to match the actual JAVA_HOME;
3. Setup Eclipse to launch from the desired JVM by customizing the eclipse.ini using this information: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#eclipse.ini
4. Also, can you specify the -classpath option when Eclipse is launched?

Comment: There's so many places to specify classpath. I tried several, but to no luck. What worked, though, was running ldconfig with the path to the missing libraries

Comment: Right. That makes perfect sense. They are not Java libraries, but Linux libraries. I read the question too fast and forgot to mention the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which might have also done the trick. Here is more information with a few options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743233/is-usr-local-lib-searched-for-shared-libraries

Comment: Eclipse may use an internal JRE if shipped with one (IBM does this).  The default downloads from Eclipse.org do not contain these, and relies on the default java command.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen -- That may be the case now, but four years ago when this was answered Eclipse came bundled with its own compiler and JRE. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746341/do-i-need-to-install-java-sdk-if-i-have-eclipse .

Comment: @ingyhere Even then the JRE was not included in the download even if it included its own compiler.  Please look for yourself in http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the latest version of Eclipse and running it.  For some reason it works fine.  I just ditched my older version of Eclipse.  I hope this works for others!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there are *two* Java runtimes in play here.  The one used to run Eclipse itself, and the one you want to run your code.  They do not have to be the same!

I would suggest

- Run Eclipse with a JDK that works
- Download Oracle JDK manually and unzip it to a folder in your home directory
- Tell Eclipse about this additional runtime (http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-add_new_jre.htm)
- Configure your project to use that JVM instead.  (http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-assign_default_jre.htm)

Now your own code is compiled against, and runs with Oracle Java.