# Java 6 uninstalls itself (Windows)

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, web

I have Java 8 installed on my system.

Now I have to develop a software for a customer that runs on Java 6. So I installed the JRE 6 on my system too. (So I can develop with the Java 6 dependencies) But JRE 6 keeps uninstalling itself. How to deal with this problem?

Comment: what do you mean by it uninstalls itself? if you check in control panel- add-remove programs, is it there?

Comment: You need a JDK to develop not a JRE

Comment: Another way is unpack it manually, than add **Installed JRE** in Eclipse. Please refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6571736

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, that is not entirely true. For example, you can get Eclipse to run and compile using only the JRE.

Comment: @KevinO If you can compile, it means that you use a JDK because you don't have javac in a JRE

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, No, it is possible to compile without the JDK. One can use Eclipse running only with the JRE, and compile classes just fine. Please see, e.g., [Do I need to install Java SDK if I Have Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746341/do-i-need-to-install-java-sdk-if-i-have-eclipse). I run such a configuration at work. If one is not using Eclipse, a JDK may be required, but the assertion that one **must** have the JDK to compile Java code is incorrect.

Comment: @KevinO And how Eclipse compiles? With a JDK even if it is included, it is still a JDK. Have look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, the fact that Eclipse uses its [own internal compiler (that only needs the JRE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642338/how-does-eclipse-compile-classes-with-only-a-jre) does not mean that one must install the JDK to run Eclipse or compile code from with in. To say that a "JDK" is included in Eclipse is not helpful. The point is that an individual can download the Oracle JRE (*not the JDK*), download Eclipse, and develop Java programs. The JDK is a specific superset of the JRE.