# Does Eclipse use the build-in compiler on export function?

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, export

I recently found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642338/java-eclipse-how-does-eclipse-compile-classes-with-only-a-jre). It basically says that Eclipse has a modified build-in compiler. It creates class files even if the java files contain errors.

Is this modified compiler used to create bytecode if I use the export function in Eclipse?

Comment: the export function...how? There are tons of options there. You mean a jar?

Comment: @Bozho, yes I mean exporting the project as jar file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Eclipse does not use javac or any other compiler at all. If you want to compile your code using another compiler, you'll have to write your own build to do that.