# Compilation errors in Jenkins but not in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, jvm, jenkins

We're coding a Java6 project under Eclipse Indigo and we currently have some compilations differences between our dev environment under Eclipse and our integration one with Jenkins.

- Our Eclipse are under **Windows 7 with JDK 1.6.0_30**.
- Jenkins is under **Linux with JDK 1.6.0_31** (also tested with version 1.6.0_24).

---

The fact is that we're getting some compilation errors *only* on Jenkins, like:

- `both define … but with unrelated return types` when an interface inherits from two interfaces which declare the same method (with different but compliant types)
- `no unique maximal instance exists for type variable B with upper bounds I,…` for some methods that return a raw type `B` instead of more specific `B<C>`.

---

The question here is not to solve this problems; with a few changes in our source code we succeeded in making Jenkins compiled.

The question is: **why does Jenkins compile in an other way than our Eclipse?** Is there some magical parameters given to the compiler or the JVM that could make such a big difference?

Comment: What kind of jenkins job do you have? Maven?

Comment: How do you build your projects? With Maven?

Comment: Well, you have Maven build VS Eclipse *full* build VS Eclipse [Incremental build](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_make_my_compiler_incremental%3F). It's best to try the same build as Jenkins locally. You could also have classpath inconsistencies.

Comment: Oups, I forgot to mention: yes, we use Maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse uses its own compiler. In a very few cases there are little differences between the Eclipse Compiler and the OpenJDK one. For more general information see also:

http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/

[How does Eclipse compile classes with only a JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642338/java-eclipse-how-does-eclipse-compile-classes-with-only-a-jre)

**Edit:**

The compilation error with the interfaces might be related to this JDK bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6908259

Comment: I didn't know Eclipse has its own über-compiler, thanks for highlighting that :)