# IntelliJ JDK not installed

Tags: intellij-idea, java

I just installed intelliJ and tried to import an eclipse project. I have a jre installed but no jdk. It doesnt want to compile without a jdk. What am I doing wrong? Do I need one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need it. JRE required only to run java programs. JDK - for development.

Comment: No, Apparently eclipse doesnt need one, its built in. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642338/how-does-eclipse-compile-classes-with-only-a-jre

Comment: eclipse *does* need a compiler, even if it's bundled along with the IDE. IntelliJ only comes with a JRE, and needs an external compiler to build your projects.