# How its possible for eclipse to compile and run programs on JRE without JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, jvm

I have installed JRE 1.7 in my system and no JDK and when I wrote a program in eclipse, eclipse is still able to compile it and run it.  As per my knowledge, compiler is available in JDK and interpreter is available in JRE. Interpreter will take .class files. But what about .java files?

Is it because of JIT compiler which is available in JVM?

Comment: Eclipse has its own Java compiler

Comment: I think here is your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642338/how-does-eclipse-compile-classes-with-only-a-jre

Comment: Even though Eclipse can compile with only a JRE it is still better to use a JDK because then Eclipse will have access to the runtime library JavaDoc and source code.